# Changing color of fontawesome fa-circle

Tags: font-awesome

Hi I have the following code:

```
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
```

`.icon-background1 {
    color: #ffc0ff;
}`

However the color of the circle doesn't change.

Any tips to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

The code written seems legit, I've used it successfully in Code Pen  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxMPVZ.
I've also included an example where the color of inner icon is set (instead of using fa-inverse).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-balance-scale fa-stack-1x icon-background2"></i>
</span>

.icon-background1 {
    color: #ffc0ff;
}
.icon-background2 {
    color: purple;
}
```